# store the content of an html-file into an jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hy erveryone,

I try to store the content of an HTML-File into an array-element with the
help of jquery.

If I try:

```
$(document).ready(

        function(){

            html = $.parseHTML( '<p>say hello</p><p>or not</p><h3>just naother TAG</h3>' );


            alert(html[0].innerHTML);
            alert(html[1].innerHTML);
            alert(html[2].innerHTML);

    });
```

everything is fine.

But if I replace the String in the Brackets of parseHTML into an html-file
like shown

```
$(document).ready(

        function(){

            html = $.parseHTML( 'navi.html' );


            alert(html[0].innerHTML);
            alert(html[1].innerHTML);
            alert(html[2].innerHTML);

});
```

the alert-box tells me "undefined".

The content of the navi.html-File is

```
<p>say hello</p><p>or not</p><h3>just another TAG</h3>
```

Could you please help me?

I already read similiar examples but I couldn't reach the goal.

thanks,
Thorsten

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.parseHTML` does not get files, it parses HTML from strings, and that's it.

If you wanted to get the file, you'd have to use ajax, for instance `$.get`

```
$.get('navi.html', function(data) {
    console.log( data );
}, 'html');
```

Adding the dataType at the end invokes `$.parseHTML` automagically, and parses the returned data

Comment: You already need `html= $(data);`  in order to `html[0].innerHTML;` works as expected.

Comment: @myjday - you're welcome! Remember to accept the answer.